# Using <!-- ko if: (customer.isLoggedIn) --> in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, customer, template

So I see this works in

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html on line 15:

<!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
```

But how do I use this in other files like:

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the XML?

I also tried just using PHP within content.html, but I'm guessing the KO does something to try to parse it.

Comment: Not quite. It has to do with JS--that's knockout JS syntax. Every view/frontend/web/template/* file has a corresponding view/frontend/web/js/* file with data and logic. That condition is referring to a customer object within the JS component. If your minicart component doesn't have the customer info, you'd have to extend it to make that available. Also, you can't use PHP in KO (.html) templates.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. But that definitely makes some easy stuff really hard. Like for example if I want to get the base url in php I just use: <?php echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>. How do you do that easily in knockout?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to basically have a roundabout way of detecting if a user is logged in. If a user is not logged in then customer().firstname returns null so it does what you expect. I haven't figured out how to return the base URL inside knockout js though since you can't use PHP inside KO templates.

```
<li class="minicart-nav-item" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
                 <a class="customer-name" href="<?php /* echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>customer/account/logout">
                    Sign Out <span data-bind="text: customer().firstname"></span>
                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().firstname -->
                <a class="customer-name" href="<?php /* echo $block->getUrl(''); ?>customer/account/login/">
                    Sign In
                </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            </li>

            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "*": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                            "components": {
                                "customer": {
                                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: If you go this way, then you don't even have to use Knockout -- you can detect existence of "log out" or "sign out" link.